# How to include Google fonts

Tags: theme-development

I'm converting an html/css template to a WordPress theme. The index.html contains the following Google font which I want to include in the header.php :
http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif' rel='stylesheet'>
Kindly advise how I can do this.

Regards

Debashis

Answer (score 2):

As you probably know it's always a good idea to [register](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_style) and [enqueue](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) your styles within you `functions.php`.

As you can see in the Codex, there is a given order for the parameters of those functions. Simply put the data of the webfont in:

```
wp_register_style( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $media );
wp_enqueue_style( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $media );
```

So you'll probably have something like this in your `functions.php`:

```
function load_google_webfonts() {
    wp_register_style( 'bree', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif' );
        wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array('bree'), '1.0', 'all');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_google_webfonts' );
```

Comment: Created the function in the function in the functions.php but this hasn't had any effect.

Comment: Ensure that you have included the `wp_head()` template tag in your Theme, usually in `header.php`, immediately before the closing HTML `</head>` tag.

Comment: You can use the font within your `style.css` like this: `body { font-family: 'Bree Serif', serif; }`